# Best way to handle boundary check for 2D list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have one 2D list like following, I want to change cell value from 1 to 0 if the cell surrounding cell is 0
like

```
from
[
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
]
To
[
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
]
```

I think I can use 8 if/else logic to check but wondering if there is a better or clean way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I will make use of python generator to get the valid neighbors, and use the `all` to check if all the neighbors are zero.

```py
def update_cell(grid):
    if not grid or not grid[0]:
        return
    m, n = len(grid), len(grid[0])

    def is_valid(i, j):
        return 0 <= i < m and 0 <= j < n

    def neighbors(i, j):
        for di, dj in [(0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (-1, -1), (1, -1), (1, 1)]:
            ni, nj = i+di, j+dj
            if is_valid(ni, nj):
                yield ni, nj

    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            if grid[i][j] and all(not grid[ni][nj] for ni, nj in neighbors(i, j)):
                grid[i][j] = 0


if __name__ == "__main__":

    grid = [
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    ]

    update_cell(grid)

    print(grid)

   # prints
   #[[0, 0, 1, 0, 0], 
   # [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], 
   # [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
   # [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
   # [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
   # [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sum the 3x3 list-list around the point in question.  Iff the sum is `1` (value of the center cell), you set it to `0`.

To pick out the 3x3 segment, you can

- Iterate over the 3x3 slices you want.
- Use slices of slices to make a new 3x3 segment for each check.
- Convert your list-list to a NumPy 2D array; NumPy has nice slicing capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write the if's, but generating neighbors as in the other answer is elegant.

If you can alter the data structure *and* need speed then you can use ghost cells.

Surround your grid with zeros like this :

```
       0 0 0 0
1 2    0 1 2 0
4 5    0 4 5 0
       0 0 0 0
```

Then you can iterate from 1..n-1 and always have all neighbours

Answer (score -1):

One way would be:

```
def neighbors(m,r,c):
    return sum((
        sum(m[r-1][max(0,c-1):c+2]) if 0 <= r-1 < len(m) else 0,
        sum(m[r  ][max(0,c-1):c+2]) if 0 <= r   < len(m) else 0,
        sum(m[r+1][max(0,c-1):c+2]) if 0 <= r+1 < len(m) else 0,
    )) - m[r][c]
```

It takes the sum of the 3x3 square around the `(r,c)` element, then subtracts the value at `(r,c)`.

There are innumerable ways to clean this up based on preference, for example:

```
def neighbors(m,r,c):
    return sum(
        sum(m[x][max(0,c-1):c+2]) for x in [r-1,r,r+1] if 0 <= x < len(m)
    ) - m[r][c]
```

The only real somewhat clever thing here is that you can sort of side-step out of bounds errors by using slicing.  So `x = [1,2,3]; print(x[100:200])` will just print an empty list, no `IndexError`.

Do I think you should use this code instead of a simple nested for loop?  *Almost definitely not.*